# Cloudkit fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler very slow response time

Tags: ios, performance, swift, asynchronous, cloudkit

I am getting really really slow response times with fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler
It takes 10 seconds+ to fetch the user record id sometimes even a full minute or longer.
A simple request like that can't take that long. And a few times it took only a few seconds...

I presume it has something todo with the priority of the operation since cloudkit works asynchronously. Maybe there's someway to change this like you can do with a CKOperation by changing queuePriority.

Right now I am testing with this simple code, to make sure it works still the slow response times are there. Of course my xcode project is bigger but this code gets called directly in the view did load method as the first thing.

```
CKContainer.defaultContainer().fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler({ (userRecordId: CKRecordID!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        println(userRecordId)
    })
```

Thank in advance  :smile:

I have looked at other answers around slowness of cloudkit but most of them only say to wrap UI code in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { }
```

inside the completion block. But doesn't really make a difference
(Sorry for any language mistakes, not native...)

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I've been facing a similar issue on another seemingly simple CK query operation.

Comment: Not really, it just started to work a little faster... One thing to note if you're using ios9 and are on cellular for example than some operations can be pushed to the back.  You can adjust the qualityOfService to solve this problem... If you want you can read more about it here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html

Comment: Yes I discovered the QoS setting but it hasn't helped. I got his amazing response from DTS today . . . Yes, I insist that querying 50 records should not take 20 seconds </rant>

> There is no way to guarantee that an Internet service, like CloudKit,
> can get your query and return the data back within a predictable
> interval. If you insist that CloudKit should be faster, please file a
> bug. If you choose to do that, please follow the guide here to gather
> the logs and attach to your bug report. 
> 
> Best Regards,
> 
> Developer Technical Support  Apple Worldwide Developer Relations

Comment: I am finding same issue- When I am updating any record on iCloud then the response time is very random. It is taking 5-25 minutes for updation.
Updation of records taking too much time than expected.

Comment: Any comment on this?